# Issue with Email Alert in the field 'from email address'

Tags: process-builder, email-template, email-alert

I'm trying to create an email alert for notifying the case submitter through email. I've set up email-to-case automation and now I'm working on the response email. I'm stuck at the 'from email address' field as it has only one option 'current user's email address' but I wanted to set the field as 'techsupport@xxxxx.com' which is a google group mail id. How do I access the other options as well?

P.S. I had previously used auto-response rule but it required a different email address than the one used in email-to-case but I wanted to use the same email as the one used in email-to-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create an Organization Wide Email Address](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_manage_orgwide_email_addresses.htm&type=5). Salesforce will ask you to verify it at the "techsupport@" alias. Once it's verified you'll be able to use it in email alerts.